# Why a segmentation fault happens only when array of choices is 3 or 7 elements?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, ncurses

I'm a beginner in C and trying to develop a small software in ncurses, with menu driven interface. I have this code, that is from http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/menus.html.

I don't understand why if I initialize an array of choices of 3 or 7 items the program goes segfault, but is fine if the array is any other size.

Here is the code. If adding 1 to n_choices or calloc() call, then segmentation fault doesn't happen. i.e.

```
my_items = (ITEM **)calloc(n_choices + 1, sizeof(ITEM *));
```

Why 3 and 7 are "special"???

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <menu.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))

WINDOW *mywin;
int rows, cols, h, w, starty, startx;
int wybeg, wxbeg, wymax, wxmax;

// choices
char *choices[] = {
    "Choice 1",
    "Choice 2",
    "Choice 3",
    "Choice 4",
    "Choice 5",
    "Choice 6",
    "Choice 7",
};
void func(char*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ITEM **my_items;
    int c;              
    MENU *my_menu;
    int n_choices, i;
    ITEM *cur_item;

    initscr(); //creates stdscr
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    if(has_colors() == TRUE){
        start_color();
        init_pair(1,COLOR_YELLOW,COLOR_BLUE);
    }

    getmaxyx(stdscr, rows, cols);
    h = rows-4;
    w = cols;
    starty = 1;
    startx = 0;

    char quitHint[] = "<Press q to exit>";

    move(0,0);
    mvprintw(LINES-1, COLS-1-strlen(quitHint), "%s", quitHint);
    refresh();

    mywin = newwin(h,w,starty,startx);
    keypad(mywin,TRUE);
    box(mywin,0,0);
    wbkgd(mywin,COLOR_PAIR(1));
    wrefresh(mywin);

    // MENU
    /* Create items */
    /**************************/
    /* FROM HERE IS THE POINT */
    /**************************/
    // if choices is 3 or 7 elements, segfault occurs! If adding +1 n_choices segfault doesn't occur
    n_choices = ARRAY_SIZE(choices);
    my_items = (ITEM **)calloc(n_choices, sizeof(ITEM *));
    for(i = 0; i < n_choices; ++i){
        my_items[i] = new_item(choices[i], choices[i]);
        /* Set the user pointer */
        set_item_userptr(my_items[i], func);
    }

    mvprintw(LINES-2,2,"sizeof(choices) = %3d | sizeof(*choices) = %3d | n_choices = %3d", sizeof(choices), sizeof(*choices), n_choices);

    /* Create menu */
    my_menu = new_menu((ITEM **)my_items);

    /* Set main window and sub window */
    set_menu_win(my_menu, mywin);
    set_menu_sub(my_menu, derwin(mywin, n_choices, 38, 2, 2));

    /* Set menu mark to the string " * " */
    set_menu_mark(my_menu, " * ");
    refresh();

    set_menu_fore(my_menu, COLOR_PAIR(1) | A_REVERSE);  // selected
    set_menu_back(my_menu, COLOR_PAIR(1));                          // unselected

    /* Post the menu */
    post_menu(my_menu);
    wrefresh(mywin);

    while((c = wgetch(mywin)) != 'q')
    {
        switch(c)
        {   case KEY_DOWN:
                menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_DOWN_ITEM);
                break;
        case KEY_UP:
            menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_UP_ITEM);
            break;
        case 10: /* enter */
        {
            /* execute func() from item pointer */
            ITEM *cur;
            void (*p) (char *);

            cur = current_item(my_menu);
            p = item_userptr(cur);
            p((char *)item_name(cur));
            pos_menu_cursor(my_menu);
            break;
        }
        }
        wrefresh(mywin);
    }

    /* Unpost and free all the memory taken up */
    unpost_menu(my_menu);
    free_menu(my_menu);
    for(i = 0; i < n_choices; ++i){
        free_item(my_items[i]);
    }

    endwin();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void func(char *local_choice){  
    mvwprintw(mywin,h-2, 2, "Item selected is : %s", local_choice);
    wclrtoeol(mywin);
    box(mywin,0,0);
    wrefresh(mywin);
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -lmenu -lncurses`

Running Debian Buster `4.19.0-2-686 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.16-1 (2019-01-17) i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: What does your debugger say? Which statement crashes?

Comment: `set_item_userptr(my_items[i], func);` to be the basis of compiler complaints, e.g. `"note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(char *)"`

Comment: You are passing a function pointer where a character pointer is expected. How should this work? `void*` is only compatible to data pointers, not code.

Comment: I'm sorry, until 10 days ago I never coded anything in C. I don't know how to use a debugger, but will try. Anyway, I figured out that crash happens at line 83, at new_menu().

Compiled with `gcc -lmenu -lncurses` always compiles without errors, but if *choices contains 3 or 7 items then segfault happens. For any other size, everithing works.

 Running on debian buster:
`4.19.0-2-686 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.16-1 (2019-01-17) i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: I've seen now that in the "example 18. Menu basics" on the linked page [tldp.org](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/menus.html) there is a `n_choices + 1` in the `calloc()` call:

```
n_choices = ARRAY_SIZE(choices);
my_items = (ITEM **)calloc(n_choices + 1, sizeof(ITEM *));
```

Maybe the author had the same error and decided to allocate some extra memory? But why 3 and 7 are "special" size and trig the segfault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe the author had the same error and decided to allocate some extra memory? But why 3 and 7 are "special" size and trig the segfault?

No, this is *wanted* by `new_menu` function:

The `new_menu` function expects that the `items`  list to be terminated by a `NULL` element.

If you read `new_menu` documentation ([menu_new.3x.html](ftp://ftp.invisible-island.net/ncurses/current/ncurses-6.1-20190302.tgz)), you can see:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> `#include <menu.h>` 
> `MENU *new_menu(ITEM **items);`
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> `The  function new_menu creates a new menu connected to a specified item` 
> `pointer array` **`(which must be NULL-terminated)`**`.`

---

So the crash you see in 3 and 7 case is -I think- related to how are stored the data in memory. One thing you can do is to dump the `my_items` memory + one element to a file just before calling the `new_menu` function.

I guess you will have some 0 value just after the elements but not in 3 and 7 cases. (My guess some 4-multiple callocation effect)